# Woocommerce Product Titles Showing HTML?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Recently, my Wordpress site was updated and the Woocommerce product pages are now showing the `<br>` code in our product titles as text.

Displays: `"New <br> Collection"` on product page.

In page source, the code is showing as

```
<h1 class="product_title entry-title">
    New&lt;br&gt;Collection</h1>
<p class="price"></p>
```

How do I fix this so there is a line break to display the product title as... 
"New 
Collection"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's only HTML here, nothing else per the tags.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Perhaps there would be a woocommerce expert who told them what setting to change to not mess with their HTML

Comment: @mplungjan Hard to say. I am just wondering why this was tagged as such. Using those tags makes the question unclear and misleading, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from @mplungjan is really  useful. I waste hours to try to found a PHP solution without success. JS code do not decrease performance at all, the only problem is that in case your DOM loading is slow, the chars could be displayed in page, before script change it. I added it in function.php @mplungjan suggest like below.
This issue is appeared after WooCommerce plugin upgrade. This happen only in single product page and is not displayed in Titles inside products list page.

Added it:

```php
     /***********************************************************************
     *  CODE FOR line BREAK in the title of woocommerce product
     * 
     ************************************************************************/
         
         function title_br_hook_javascript() {
             ?>
                 <script>
                   window.addEventListener("load",function() {
           [...document.querySelectorAll(".product_title")].forEach(h => h.innerHTML = h.innerHTML.replace(/&lt;br&gt;/g,"<br/>"));
                      console.log("restore prod's title br");
         }) 
                 </script>
             <?php
         }
         add_action('wp_head', 'title_br_hook_javascript');
```

Comment: This solution is not so elegant because  the replaced character appear before JS function execution. Does anyone open a ticket on woocommerce for it?

Comment: So you take my code and wrap it and get voted up? Strange

Comment: Sorry it is my first post in SO...How can vote you up....? I tryed it but platform say i don not have engouh score to vote you up

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot fix it in code then try

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".product_title")].forEach(h => h.innerHTML = h.innerHTML.replace(/&lt;br&gt;/g,"<br/>"))
})
```

```html
<h1 class="product_title">A split&lt;br&gt;title</h1>
<h1 class="product_title">A split&lt;br&gt;title</h1>
```